# Rmultinom with a function containing Inf: illogical error?

Tags: r

```
f1 = function(x){1-f2(x)}
f2 = function(x){exp(x*as.numeric(x<5))}
f12 = c(f1,f2)

f3 = function(x){1-f4(x)}
f4 = function(x){exp(as.numeric(x<5))}
f34 = c(f3,f4)    

rmultinom(n=1,size=1,prob=sapply(f12, \(x) x(Inf))) %% output gives error. See below

rmultinom(n=1,size=1,prob=sapply(f34, \(x) x(Inf))) %% output as expected. [0,1] or [1,0].
```

The first rmultinom call gives "Error in rmultinom(n = 1, size = 1, prob = sapply(f12, function(x) x(Inf))) : NA in probability vector". The second one is fine. The only difference is that f2 contains an "x" term that f4 does not. Why is this an error? The fact that x is infinity should not matter, because anything greater than or equal to 5 turns to zero.

Comment: `f1(Inf)` and `f2(Inf)` both give `NaN`.  Infinity is not "greater than" a finite number, because <handwave=on>"greater than" is only defined for the reals<handwave=off>.  So you're `sapply`ing `NaN` as the value to `probs` in your call to `rmultinom`.  The behaviour is correct and expected.

Comment: @Limey then why do f3(Inf) and f4(Inf) work? They have the same condition. The problem is with the factor x multiplying the condition, not the condition itself

Comment: Because the error checking in `exp()` is different to the error checking in `rmultinorm`.  `exp` chooses to handle underflows and overflows elegantly and return `NaN` (silently).  `rmultinorm`, not unreasonably, expects probabilities to lie between `0` and `1` and chooses to throw an exception when they do not.  `NaN` does not lie in this range.